# AVAudioPlayer with remote control events

Tags: ios

I have a problem to work with `AVAudioPlayer`. I used AVAudioPlayer to play a audio resource file. I use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

to handle remote control event

When in background mode (Lock screen) [image] 
I press `Pause` button on lock screen, `Remote control events` was hidden, don't change to `Play` button. Even though I don't set any code to `endReceivingRemoteControlEvents` 
[image] 
The code to handle `Remote Control Events`

```
 - (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        //if it is a remote control event handle it correctly
        if (event.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {
            if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay) {
                [audioPlayer play];
            } else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause) {
                [audioPlayer pause];
            } else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause) {
                [self togglePlayPause];
            }
        }
    }
```

What happen with `Remote control events` after press `Pause` button, please help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have just found the problem, just set `nowPlayingInfo`. NSDictionary *lockScreenInfo = @{ MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:@"SPP" };
        [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo = lockScreenInfo;